# Where can I find the HttpTester class in Jetty 9.3.1?

Tags: jetty

In the Jetty 9.3.1 [documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/LocalConnector.html) the Class `HttpTester` is referenced, however it doesn't appear to be in any of the jar files provided in the [download](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html) package.

```
 HttpTester.Request request = HttpTester.newRequest();
  request.setURI("/some/resource");
  HttpTester.Response response = 
      HttpTester.parseResponse(HttpTester.from(localConnector.getResponse(request.generate())));
```

I want to use `HttpTester.Response` and `HttpTester.Request` in my unit test cases.

Was this class removed in 9.3.1? If so, is there a recommended alternative?

Answer (score 4):

It was moved to the `tests` classified artifacts.

Try this (in maven-speak):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.11.v20160721</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't use maven. Is there a way I can access it using pure Java?

Comment: This artifact is not part of the distribution, it will never be available on http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html .  Use gradle, or ant+ivy, or buildr, or groovy grape, or sbt, or leiningen then (they can all access the artifact).  You **really** should use a build tool, any build tool, otherwise you'll rip your hair out tracking down the dependencies you need (Jetty has over 110!).  You can also use [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jetty-http%22%20AND%20l%3A%22tests%22).

Comment: So in summary, I need to do a custom build of the Jetty source code using that maven rule change to export the artifact?

Comment: This is probably a less than ideal solution, but I downloaded the Jetty source and put HttpTester.java in my code.